# How to use command grep with several lines?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep, solaris

With a shell script I'm looking for a way to make the grep command do one of the following two options:

a) Use the grep command to display the following 10 lines of a match in a file; ie, the command `grep "pattern" file.txt` will result in all lines of the file that has that pattern:

```
patternrestoftheline

patternrestofanotherline

patternrestofanotherline

...
```

So I'm looking for this:

```
patternrestoftheline

following line

following line

...

until the tenth

patternrestofanotherline

following line

following line

...

until the tenth
```

b) Use the grep command to display all lines within two patterns as if they were limits

```
patternA restoftheline

anotherline

anotherline

...

patternB restoftheline
```

I do not know if another command instead of grep is a better option.
I'm currently using a loop that solves my problem but is line by line, so with extremely large files takes too much time.

I'm looking for the solution working on Solaris.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your first task, use the `-A` ("after") option of `grep`:

```
grep -A 10 'pattern' file.txt
```

The second task is a typical `sed` problem:

```
sed -ne '/patternA/,/patternB/p' file.txt
```

Comment: the option -A is not working on Solaris, but se solved the problem

Comment: grep -A is not supported by Solaris's default /usr/bin/grep or /usr/xpg4/grep.  That is part of GNU coreutils which may or may not be installed on Solaris.   @Uwe -1

Comment: Sorry, then you either have to use rici's awk solution or install GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 1):

In case (a), What do you expect to happen if the pattern occurs within the 10 lines?

Anyway, here are some awk scripts which should work (untested, though; I don't have Solaris):

```
# pattern plus 10 lines
awk 'n{--n;print}/PATTERN/{if(n==0)print;n=10}'

# between two patterns
awk '/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN2/{print}'
```

The second one can also be done similarly with `sed`

Comment: Use nawk, not awk on Solaris - /usr/bin/awk is an old version.